# Shopify show average or total rating badge on collection page

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I need to display average rating on collection page below collection name (total rating of all products for specific collection).

I have searched in google for shopify script and app but couldn't find any solution for this. If anybody have done this type of task then please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what a rating is. Is it a number? If so, where does it come from. Once you know where this number is, you could add up all the products you render on the page, or in the collection, and display the number.

If you do not know how to assign a rating number to a product, the easiest method is most likely by attaching an integer Metafield resource to each product with the number you want. Shopify has plenty of free tools and documentation on how to do this.